# JButton .doClick() without doing anything?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Is it possible to simulate a click on a button, similar to doClick() but just graphical simulate it, not generate any ActionEvent´s. If know that i can extend the class, do my own doClick with a simple if-statement. But is it any other possibility?

I want to this because I have a button that the user can press, but sometimes the computer (it s in a game) "presses" the button. All the logic is done in another thread, I just wanna display it for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dig into the details in the look and feel you're using, you might be able to see how it detects and paints the button in its "down" state, and then simulate that?

or you could extend/implement ButtonModel, and mess with the setPressed/isPressed state?

Comment: I think the simplest solutions is to just check the model in the actionlistener, to detect if it was a manual press or a computer press. But im still interesting if there is any solutions to just graphicaly "click" on the button.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the simplest solutions is to just check the model in the `ActionListener`.

I don't see a way to distinguish between the two; the model is oblivious as to who calls its methods. Instead, you could save all the listeners, invoke `doClick()`, and restore the listeners. It looks like you would have to check action, change and item listeners.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on the button try this:

```
try
        {
            robot = new Robot();
            robot.mouseMove(0,500);
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        }catch(Exception e){}
```

But maybe you will prefer to simply disable the button when the user shouldn't click it

`Button.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: The problem is that I want it to look like a click, graphicaly. But not to generate any actions (or maybe some kind of other action i can "throw away" in the listener).

Answer (score 0):

You can set whether it's enabled or not, so use "buttonName.setEnabled(false);"